# R - group by 2 variables and set highest value as new column?

Tags: r

I have the following data

```
df <- data.frame("group1" = c("A","B","B","C","D","D","C","E","E","A","B","B","C","D","D","C","E","E"),
                 "group2" = c("X","Y","Z","Z","W","F","Z","N","M","D","F","U","T","R","R","S","S","O"),
                 "val" = c(232,200,3321,400,600,500,22,33,1200,555,200,888,43,600,500,800,900,3213))
```

I want to add two new columns:

- Column 1 will show the group2 value which has the highest "val" for each group1 value
- Column 2 will do the same thing, but it will show the percentage of the total that the highest value is

So, firstly grouping the data:

```
df %>% group_by(group1,group2) %>% summarise("totalval" = sum(val)) %>% arrange(group1, desc(totalval))
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   group1 [5]
   group1 group2 totalval
   <fct>  <fct>     <dbl>
 1 A      D           555
 2 A      X           232
 3 B      Z          3321
 4 B      U           888
 5 B      F           200
 6 B      Y           200
 7 C      S           800
 8 C      Z           422
 9 C      T            43
10 D      R          1100
11 D      W           600
12 D      F           500
13 E      O          3213
14 E      M          1200
15 E      S           900
16 E      N            33
```

So I want column 1 to have the value "D" as the value "D" in the group2 column has the highest value in all of group 1. Column 2 would show the value 555 / (555 + 232) = 0.70 for all rows which have a value of "A" in the group1 column.

I found a way to get column 1 by creating a temp table with the highest values then left joining that back onto the main table, but I think it is rather convoluted - I am sure there's a cleaner way. I also am not sure how to get the percentages (column 2 as described above) to be added.

My solution thus far:

```
#add in overall val to use for percentages
df <- df %>% group_by(group1) %>% mutate("g1_total_val" = sum(val)) %>% ungroup()

#create temp table with selected values
t2 <- df %>% group_by(group1,group2) %>% summarise("totalval" = sum(val)) %>% arrange(group1, desc(totalval)) %>% 
        slice(1:1) %>% mutate("highest_g2" = group2) %>% select(group1, highest_g2)

df <- df %>% left_join(t2,on = "group1")
```

Any help on how to get column 2 and an easier way to add on column 1 would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `which.max` to get the index of the maximum value for the first column, and divide the `max` by the `sum` for the second column as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(group1, group2) %>%
  summarise(totalval = sum(val)) %>%
  arrange(group1, desc(totalval)) %>% 
  mutate(col1 = group2[which.max(totalval)],
         col2 = max(totalval) / sum(totalval))
```

Which gives:

```
   group1 group2 totalval col1   col2
   <fct>  <fct>     <dbl> <fct> <dbl>
 1 A      D           555 D     0.705
 2 A      X           232 D     0.705
 3 B      Z          3321 Z     0.721
 4 B      U           888 Z     0.721
 5 B      F           200 Z     0.721
 6 B      Y           200 Z     0.721
 7 C      S           800 S     0.632
 8 C      Z           422 S     0.632
 9 C      T            43 S     0.632
10 D      R          1100 R     0.5  
11 D      W           600 R     0.5  
12 D      F           500 R     0.5  
13 E      O          3213 O     0.601
14 E      M          1200 O     0.601
15 E      S           900 O     0.601
16 E      N            33 O     0.601
```

**Edit**
If you want to keep the original number of rows, you should replace `summarise` with `mutate`, as such:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group1, group2) %>%
  mutate(totalval = sum(val)) %>%
  group_by(group1) %>% 
  arrange(group1, desc(totalval)) %>% 
  mutate(col1 = group2[which.max(totalval)],
         col2 = max(totalval) / sum(totalval))
```

Note that `summarise` automatically 'peels off' the second grouping variable, but `mutate` does not, so I re-do the grouping manually.
This gives the original 18 rows with 2 columns added.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My actual data has many more columns so summarise will mess up the data (sorry i shouldve mentioned it). Is there a way without summarise?

Comment: The `summarise` was a copy-paste of the code you provided; I merely added the `mutate`. What is wrong with the summarise? Share your input data and expected output so I can help you better.

Comment: the original dataset has 18 rows and the summarise above has 16 rows - I want the end result to return to me the original dataset but with the new two columns basically. Sorry I should have made that clear

Comment: I made an edit to my answer. Does that do what you want?

Comment: Thanks! Yes it almost does, the column 1 is completely correct however the col2 formula should be max(totalval) /  sum(val) rather than sum (totalval) in the denominator. Easy fix though - thanks again!